# How to create multiple sheets using RSSheet in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, excel

I am trying to create an XLS sheet programmatically. I am able to create single sheet in the XLS file, but when I try to create two sheets, I get the error. The file is created but I am unable to open the file. I can only open the file when it is created with single sheet.

Here is what I tried:

```
RSworkBook * folder = [ [RSworkBook alloc] init];
folder.author = @"andrea cappellotto";
folder.version = 1.2;

RSworkSheet * sheet = [[RSworkSheet alloc] initWithName:@"prova"];
RSworkSheet * sheet2 = [[RSworkSheet alloc] initWithName:@"222"];

RSworkSheetRow * row = [[RSworkSheetRow alloc] initWithHeight:20];
[row addCellString:@"prova"];
[row addCellString:@"prova2"];
[sheet addWorkSheetRow:row];
[sheet2 addWorkSheetRow:row];

RSworkSheetRow * row2 = [[RSworkSheetRow alloc] initWithHeight:25];
[row2 addCellNumber:100];
[row2 addCellData:[NSDate date] ];
[sheet addWorkSheetRow:row2];
[sheet2 addWorkSheetRow:row];

[folder addWorkSheet:sheet];
[folder addWorkSheet:sheet2];

NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
[folder writeWithName:@"prova" toPath:documentsDir];
```

HEre is the xml code that is generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns:c="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:component:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:x2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2003/xml"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>andrea cappellotto</Author>
<LastAuthor>andrea cappellotto</LastAuthor>
<Created>2015-07-09</Created>
<Version>1.20</Version>
</DocumentProperties>
<OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
</OfficeDocumentSettings>
<ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
<WindowHeight>20000</WindowHeight>
<WindowWidth>20000</WindowWidth>
<WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
<WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>
<ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
<ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
</ExcelWorkbook><Styles><Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
<Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Horizontal="Center"/>
<Borders/>
<Font ss:FontName=".HelveticaNeueInterface-Regular" ss:Size="14.00" ss:Color="#000000"/>
<Interior/>
<NumberFormat/>
<Protection/>
</Style>
<Style ss:ID="s60">
<NumberFormat ss:Format="Short Date"/>
</Style>
</Styles>
<Worksheet ss:Name="prova">
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="2" ss:ExpandedRowCount="2" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="0.00" ss:DefaultRowHeight="20.00">
<Column ss:Width="80"/>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="20.00" >
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">prova</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">prova2</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="25.00" >
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="Number">100.00</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s60">
<Data ss:Type="DateTime">2015-07-09</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
</Table>
<WorksheetOptions/>
</Worksheet>
<Worksheet ss:Name="222">
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="2" ss:ExpandedRowCount="2" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="0.00" ss:DefaultRowHeight="20.00">
<Column ss:Width="80"/>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="20.00" >
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">prova</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">prova2</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="20.00" >
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">prova</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">prova2</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
</Table>
<WorksheetOptions/>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error that you receive?

Comment: I cant attach the screenshot as i dont have enough reputation. The error is that, when I try to open the excel sheet, it says cant be opened and the error type is unknown.

Comment: no code error.... nothing

Comment: Yes, you require a reputation of at least 10 to post an image. If you get one more upvote (after mine) you should be able to post the screen shot. You get +5 per upvote, for a question... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found another library to create multiple sheets in a xls file. It is libxl.I can add as many sheets as I can by using the following line:

```
 SheetHandle sheet = xlBookAddSheet(book, [sheetNAme UTF8String], NULL);
```